# Rotating labels on second axis

Tags: matplotlib

I am adding a second x-axis to my plot like this:

```
ax2 = ax.twiny()
offset = 0, -25
new_axisline = ax2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
ax2.axis["bottom"] = new_axisline(loc="bottom", axes=ax2, offset=offset)
ax2.axis["top"].set_visible(False)

ax2.set_xticks(xticks)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xticks))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(xticks_labels))
```

the problem is I don't know how I can rotate the labels from there.

Also: If I add ticks to my first axis:

```
plt.xticks(xticks1, xticks1_labels, rotation='vertical')
```

the `rotation` argument gets ignored and I don't understand why either.

I have tried

```
ax2.set_xticklabels(ax2.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

but it also has no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

You can take a look at the complete plotting logic below:

```
def event_plot(event_list, labels=None, figsize=(16, 9), padding=0.85, grid=False, title=None, colors=None):

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = SubplotHost(fig, 111)
    # ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)
    ax.grid(grid)

    if title is not None:
        ax.set_title(title)

    max_end = 0
    for i, events in enumerate(event_list):

        for event in events:
            start = event[0]
            end = event[1]
            max_end = max(max_end, end)
            y = (i, i + padding)
            c = 'red' if colors is None else colors[i]
            plt.fill_between([start, end], y[0], y2=y[1], color=c, alpha=0.35, linewidth=0.0)

    plt.legend(['Recording data available for channel'], loc='upper center')

    if labels is not None:
        labels_ids = np.asarray(range(len(labels))) + 1
        labels_y = labels_ids - 0.5 - (1 - padding) / 2.
        plt.yticks(labels_y, labels)
        for y in labels_y:
            plt.axhline(y, alpha=0.125, color='k', linestyle='--')

    return ax, fig


def plot_case_windows(all_records, case_windows, filename_title, filename=None):

    channel_event_list = list()
    labels = list()

    for group_name, group in all_records.channel_groups.items():
        [(labels.append(x[0]), channel_event_list.append(x[1])) for x in group.items()]

    recording_time = all_records.end - all_records.start

    title = 'File: {:s}, recording time: {:d} sec'.format(os.path.basename(filename_title), int(recording_time))
    ax1, fig = event_plot(channel_event_list, title=title, labels=labels)

    xticksmax = 0
    xticksmin = float('Inf')
    xticks1 = list()
    xticks1_labels = list()
    xticks2 = list()
    xticks2_labels = list()

    for case_win in case_windows:

        xticks1.append(int(case_win.start + (case_win.end - case_win.start)/2.))
        xticks2.append(case_win.start)

        xticksmax = max(xticksmax, case_win.end)
        xticksmin = min(xticksmin, case_win.start)

        xticks1_labels.append(case_win.name)
        xticks2_labels.append(str(case_win.start) + ' s')

        plt.axvline(x=case_win.start, color='k', linestyle='--')
        plt.axvline(x=case_win.end, color='k', linestyle='--')

    xticks2 = (np.asarray(xticks2) - xticksmin) / (xticksmax - xticksmin)

    plt.xlim([xticksmin, xticksmax])

    ax1.set_xticks(xticks1)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
    ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xticks1))
    ax1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(xticks1_labels))

    ax2 = ax1.twiny()

    offset = 0, -20
    new_axisline = ax2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    ax2.axis["bottom"] = new_axisline(loc="bottom", axes=ax2, offset=offset)
    ax2.axis["top"].set_visible(False)
    ax2.set_xticks(xticks2)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
    ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.FixedLocator(xticks2))
    ax2.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(xticks2_labels))

    plt.setp(ax2.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=45)

    # ax2.set_xticklabels(ax1.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=45)

    #plt.show()
    plt.tight_layout()

    if filename:
        plt.savefig(filename)
```

Comment: You use `ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())` => there is no major ticks on `ax2.xaxis` and nothing to rotate. You have to rotate minor ticks.

Comment: @Serenity That makes sense of course. I have now changed it to `plt.setp(ax2.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=45)` but it's still showing no effect.

Comment: Ok. No other clues.

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] which one can copy and run? I think by just looking at the code it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: Please try: `ax2.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set(rotation=90)`. Tell me if this works out. Ref: https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axisartist.html